# Monoid Definition

Tags: abstract-algebra, definition, monoid

A monoid is $(M,*,e)$. I am having trouble understanding what the 'multiplication' operation represents. Is it an operation for an  element which returns another element or an operation which takes two elements and returns a third one?

Comment: You can think of it as regular old associative multiplication. For example the positive integers with multiplication. But it can represent other things, such as function composition or integer addition.

Comment: Most "usual" monoids can be represented as functions with composition. But there are some monoids for which this is not true...

Comment: You have $\star:M\times M\rightarrow M$. Denoting $\star\left(a,b\right)$
by $a\star b$ you have $a\star\left(b\star c\right)=\left(a\star b\right)\star c$.
Element $e$ is characterized by $e\star a=a=a\star e$ for each $a\in M$.
It can be shown that it is unique in this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second: it represents an associative *binary* operation which takes elements, say, $a, b\in M$ and operates on them, and outputs a third (not necessarily distinct from a or b) value:

$$a * b = c, \;\quad a, b, c\in M$$

The symbol $*$ here is a "generic" symbol representing a binary operation which needs to be defined or specified: for example, addition of integers $(a + b)$, multiplication of positive integers $(a\cdot b \;\text{or just}\; ab)$.

Comment: and $e$ would be something like
a*e=a

Comment: Is it strictly on pairs of elements? Is it never the case that an element is treated individually?

Comment: Exactly. That's correct ($a*e = a)$. Treated individually? NO: The "bi" in binary requires *two* inputs. We might use, say, $a^2$ but that's just shorthand for $a*a$. Note that we still need two elements here (which may not be distinct, as in $a*a$) on which to perform the binary operation.

Comment: Thank you. Could the set $M$ include the same elements more than once and maybe including the element $e$ more than once too as long as the rules are obeyed? Since the monoid forms a category too would the morphisms be morphisms in the category?

Comment: In a set, all elements are unique. That is, $\{a, a, b, b, b, c, e\} = \{a, b, c, e\}.$ But they can each be operated on repeatedly.

Comment: I am typing some basics about these wild creatures in Abstract algebra. +1

Answer (score 0):

The second is correct.

As an example you can consider the natural numbers $(\mathbb{N},+,0)$.